# Multiplying disjoint cycles

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I've trying to multiply out this disjoint cycle in order to get the cycle from the computation $f^5$ but when I get to $f^4$ I just get stuck in a loop of 1 cycles from both the left and right cycle and I have no idea what to do next. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated, thanks

$f = (16)(96287) = (162879)$

$f^1 = (162879)(162879) = (127)(689)$
$f^2 = (127)(689)(162879) = (18)(67)(29)$
$f^3 = (18)(67)(29)(162879) = (172)(698)$
$f^4 = (172)(698)(162879) = \;(197826)$
$f^5 = (197826)(162879) = ????$

Comment: Cycles are typically applied from right to left. You have $f = (16)(96287) = (16287)$: how did you calculate this? What happened to $9$, for example?

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like your exponents are all off by $1$. For example, what you're calling $f^1$ is really $f^2$.

Comment: @Théophile Well if I'm being honest I was just following a couple of youtube tutorials and went with the method they were using. The 9? I just assumed it was one cycle and took it out but I'm pretty sure it should look like something like this instead now (162879)

Comment: Aha, that's better. Now, from $f = (162879)$, you will have $f^2 = (162879)(162879) = (127)(689)$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: Yeah I think it was just that I had it wrong from the beginning, multiplying it out should be easy enough now. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help. If you like, you can write out the answer to your own question and have the satisfaction of closing it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close. First, fixing your exponents, you should have:

$$\begin{align}
f\ \  &= (162879)\\
f^2 &= (162879)(162879) = (127)(689)\\
f^3 &= (127)(689)(162879) = (18)(67)(29)\\
f^4 &= (18)(67)(29)(162879) = (172)(698)\\
f^5 &= (172)(698)(162879) = (197826)\\
f^6 &= (197826)(162879) = \textrm{????}
\end{align}$$

Now, for the last one, it sounds like you were concerned about getting a product of $1$-cycles, but that's exactly what should happen:
$$f^6 = (1)(2)(6)(7)(8)(9),$$
which is the identity permutation on those six elements. (Side note: perhaps your permutation is actually on nine elements, but you've been omitting the $1$-cycles for $3$, $4$, and $5$? In that case, $f^6 = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)$. Either way, we could also just write something like $f^6 = \iota$ for brevity, where $\iota$ is the identity permutation.)

Note that $f$ is a $6$-cycle, so it is to be expected that after six applications, it returns to the identity.